# What's wrong with my function? C#

Tags: c#, string, function

I'm trying to create a function in c# but I can't seem to locate what's wrong with the code.
I know it's a very basic question but I really need your guys help!

Here is my code:

```
public PlayerCards(string player1C1)
{
    string p1C1 = player1C1;
    return p1C1;
}
```

These are the errors I get:

> Error    1   Method must have a return type
>
> Error    2   Since `_2_Man_Hold_Em.GameLogic.PlayerCards(string)` returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: you have not declared the return type of the PlayerCards method.

Comment: I recommend working your way through a C# tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1sx6ed2.aspx This will provide some context.

Comment: unless it's a constructor, in which case you should be setting a field/property, like "this.p1C1 = player1C1;", and not returning anything.

Comment: The first error explains the problem. You have to specify the type of value or object you will return from the method. I would recommend going through the tutorial specified by @millimoose.

Comment: **Method must have a return type**

Comment: @Ramhound And What did i say? (In fact it is not *void*, this syntax is  allowed only on constructors but they can not return anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error can help you search for "C# methods", which will lead you to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx):

> Methods are declared in a class or struct by specifying the access level such as public or private, optional modifiers such as abstract or sealed, the return value, the name of the method, and any method parameters. These parts together are the signature of the method.

The error says:

> must have a return type

Searching "return type" on that page gives you:

> If the return type, **the type listed before the method name**, is not void, the method can return the value by using the return keyword.

So between the access modifier "public" and the method name "PlayerCards" you need a "return type": `string`. It's all about definitions. If you get those, the compiler is really helpful with its errors.

Answer (score 1):

> Method must have a return type

Add a return type:

```
public string PlayerCards(string player1C1)
```

The other error goes away, too.

Answer (score 0):

You will solve this issue by adding a return type to the method if you wish to return a value.

```
public string PlayerCard(string card)
```

If you should add void to the method if you do not wish to return any value.

```
public void ProcessCard(string card)
```

Here are some resources which might be of help to you:

[C# Fundamentals: Development for Absolute Beginners](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners) -- Set of some good video on C# programming fundamentals

[C# Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)